# What is the right way to clear status by id from generic component with global persistance?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a generic feedback component which enables a component to provide a Like/Dislike feedback on a text content. I would like to clear the Like/Dislike status based on an id following a certain condition before the component is mounted (or re-mounted).

Premise:

- I need the state persistent to survive unmounts
- The feedback is regarding a text content not passed to the component
- If the text changes, the parent component should be able to clear the Like/Dislike state to be able to provide feedback on a new text.
- My main concern is that static map would become too big and cause memory issues

I Considered the following options to do it:

1. Create a static function to remove the status by id - The problem is that to use it you need to be familiar with the implementation.
2. Using a parent state context to persist the state - Not an option since this is not generic enough and requires each usage to implement its own state mechanism.
3. Send a text hash from the parent component - if the hash is not the same clear it - the problem is that it is ugly and not easy to understand.

```html
import * as React from "react";
import { FocusZone, FocusZoneDirection, IStackStyles, Link, Stack, Text } from "@fluentui/react";
import { FeedbackSource, FeedbackStatus } from "./types";
import { FeedbackItem } from "./FeedbackItem";

interface FeedbackSectionProps {
    id: FeedbackSource;
    shouldPersist?: boolean;
}

const statuses: Record<string, FeedbackStatus> = {};

export const FeedbackSection = ({ id, shouldPersist = false }: FeedbackSectionProps) => {
    const [feedbackStatus, setFeedbackStatus] = React.useState(statuses[id] || FeedbackStatus.None);
    const onClickFeedback = (feedbackStatus: FeedbackStatus) => {
        setFeedbackStatus(feedbackStatus);

        if (shouldPersist) {
            statuses[id] = feedbackStatus;
        }
    };

    return (
        <FeedbackItem
            feedbackStatus={feedbackStatus}
            feedbackItemType={FeedbackStatus.Like}
            onClickFeedback={onClickFeedback}
        />
        <FeedbackItem
            feedbackStatus={feedbackStatus}
            feedbackItemType={FeedbackStatus.Dislike}
            onClickFeedback={onClickFeedback}
        />
    );
};
```

This is how the parent component looks like, i want to clear the status when isLoading=true statically (not depend if the component is loaded - unless there is a good way to do that).

```
 <FeedbackSection id={FeedbackSource.Source1} shouldPersist={true} />
 <FeedbackSection id={FeedbackSource.Source2} />
```

Comment: Could you tell more about what tools you use for persistance? `redux-rersist`?
Do you use suspense or how do you implement loading?
Are `statuses` really stored like that?
Do you have any API calls, how do you handle it?

These questions are important so I can understand what architecture you use for helping you better.

Comment: as mentioned above the persistence is in the global variable (statuses) with no redux and I want to avoid redux as we use this component in multiple services, regarding loading - there is an API call to get some content and when we load it we also load this feedback component to get feedback on the content

Comment: My first instinct is to say that this sounds like it should be off-loaded to an API endpoint or some sort of pub-sub service -- especially if it needs to be updated for more than 1 user, be sync, and up to date. That said, without a working example, it's going to very hard to determine what would be the best approach and design pattern for your needs.

Comment: Naively, here's a working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/leverage-localstorage-custom-events-by9zmc) that leverages [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent). This approach keeps the logic abstracted while allowing the like/dislike status to be persisted across mounts/unmounts/refreshes and for it to be reset from anywhere (provided you have a valid `id`). Again, hard to say if this approach is adequate without more details.

Comment: The feedback is relevant only for the specific generated text. Once the page reloads or there's a new generated text, that feedback will no longer have use. To create a service for something like this sounds excessive.
The major "fear" here is that the page might not reload for a long while and the stored feedbacks would grow to an excessive size